# slappasswd -h {CRYPT} not working

Tags: openldap

When I try to encrypt the password by using the following command on my linux machine:

```
slappasswd -h {CRYPT}
```

I am prompted for a new password:

```
Re-enter the new password :
```

After typing this I encounter the following error:

```
Password generation failed for scheme {CRYPT}: scheme not recognized.
```

Why am I getting this error? I am using the OpenLDAP.

Answer (score 4):

this might be caused by your shell (tcsh?) treating the `{}` characters special. does

```
slappasswd -h '{CRYPT}'
```

work?

also, your openldap must be built with crypt support (`$LDAP_SRC/configure --enable-crypt`):

```
ldd /usr/sbin/slappasswd | grep libcrypt
```

(adapt the path to slappasswd as necessary) should output something.

Comment: if it helps you a lot, you might consider accepting this answer

Answer (score 2):

it could be simply that your version of openLDAP does not support the use of the CRYPT encryption scheme.

you can instead use, for instance, SSHA:

slappasswd -h {SSHA}

i had the same problem, using LDAP 2.4.33 on CentOS 6.3.